# In Dynamics CRM, how do I enable wildcard (*) search by default in Quick Find?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

In crm 2011 On-premise we had Quick Find that added automatic * at the beginning of any text search. Now it is not working.

In all lookups we have if we write abc in search it automatically adds * at the begininig but in Quick Find it does not functioning the same like lookup.

I googled it but cannot find any work around. Before Rollup 14 we were having this thing working.

Comment: Were you doing something to add the *, or was it out of the box?

Comment: No it was by default...

Comment: Doesn't sounds like something out of the box. I think that's a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer.

1. Go to the following path and find "stage.js" file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics   CRM\CRMWeb_static_common\scripts\"
2. Create a backup copy of this file before any modification, so that you have the original copy too
3. Open "stage.js" in a text editor such as EmEditor
4. Find the following line of code:

   ```js
   sFindCriteria=Trim(findCriteria.value.replace(/[\*]+/,"*"));findCriteria.value=sFindCriteria;
   ```
5. Now change it to :

   ```js
   sFindCriteria=Trim(findCriteria.value.replace(/[\*]+/,"*"));if (sFindCriteria != "" && sFindCriteria.substr(0, 1) != "*") sFindCriteria = "*" + sFindCriteria;findCriteria.value=sFindCriteria;
   ```
6. Save the file and try Quick Find to see the change

**I am updting this answer today (`23rd-Dec-2015`) because i found a better solution i posted here:**

[CRM 2011 Quick Find Search using default wildcard (*) automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400873/crm-2011-quick-find-search-using-default-wildcard-automatically/34429265#34429265)

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. Great little tweak this is.

Answer (score -1):

Non code fix:

Go into views for the entity that has problems, select Quick find view, select "Add Find Columns", select fields that need to be added to work with the wild card search, click ok, select "Add View Columns" and select columns added to "Add Find Columns", click ok, then save and close.  Last publish your entity