# CRM 2011 Quick Find Search using default wildcard (*) automatically

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have tried the following which I found in another post but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

1.Go to the following path and find "stage.js" file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb_static_common\scripts\"

2.Create a backup copy of this file before any modification, so that you have the original copy too

3.Open "stage.js" in a text editor such as EmEditor

4.Find the following line of code: sFindCriteria=Trim(findCriteria.value.replace(/[*]+/,"*"));findCriteria.value=sFindCriteria;

5.Now change it to : sFindCriteria=Trim(findCriteria.value.replace(/[*]+/,""));if (sFindCriteria != "" && sFindCriteria.substr(0, 1) != "") sFindCriteria = "*" + sFindCriteria;findCriteria.value=sFindCriteria;

6.Save the file and try Quick Find to see the change

Any ideas why this doesn't work and what I can change to get this to work??

Comment: Modifying a built-in script is an unsupported hack which I would not recommend to do. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We are trying to make it so that the quick search always uses a leading wildcard without the user having to insert it themselves. For example, we might have a company called 'The IT company' - if we only search for 'IT' this company would not be returned. We have to manually add a '*' to the search criteria e.g.'*IT'. It might be that it is just a training issue?!

Comment: I would recommend training the users. When you replace `BeginsWith` conditions by `Like` conditions, SQL Server can only perform full table scans, which potentially can degrade system performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default wildcard \* in Quick Find Crm 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405693/default-wildcard-in-quick-find-crm-2011)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your talking about this post :P
[In Dynamics CRM, how do I enable wildcard (*) search by default in Quick Find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405693/default-wildcard-in-quick-find-crm-2011)

I asked the same Question in 2014, but now i have got the solution. I agree with `Henk van Boeijen` modifying the built-in script is an un-supported way, so i found a supported way.

**Write a plugin:**

```
  public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        string OriginalSearchQueryString = String.Empty;
        string UpdatedOriginalQueryToLikeQuery = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext ContextInstance = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationService ServiceInstance = ((IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory))).CreateOrganizationService(ContextInstance.InitiatingUserId);
            // Critical Point here - NOTICE that the InputParameters Contains the word Query
            if (ContextInstance.Depth < 2 && ContextInstance.InputParameters.Contains(QueryLiteral) && ContextInstance.InputParameters[QueryLiteral] is QueryExpression)
            {

                QueryExpression QueryPointer = (ContextInstance.InputParameters[QueryLiteral] as QueryExpression);
                //Verify the conversion worked as expected - if not, everything else is useless
                if (null != QueryPointer)
                {
                    // Check if the request is coming from any Search View 
                    // We know this b/c Criteria isn't null and the Filters Count > 1
                    if (null != QueryPointer.Criteria && (QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters.Count > 1 || QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters.Count == 1))
                    {
                        if (QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters.Count > 1 && QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions.Count > 0 && QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions[0].Values.Count > 0)
                            OriginalSearchQueryString = QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[1].Conditions[0].Values[0].ToString();
                        else if (QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters.Count == 1 && QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions.Count > 0 && QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions[0].Values.Count > 0)
                            OriginalSearchQueryString = QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions[0].Values[0].ToString();

                        if (CheckIfTheQueryIsNotForWebResourceAndSearchIsNotByLetter(ContextInstance.PrimaryEntityName, OriginalSearchQueryString))
                        {
                            OriginalSearchQueryString = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}", LIKE, OriginalSearchQueryString);
                            OriginalSearchQueryString = ModifyAllConditionExpressionsInCriteriaToLikeOperator(OriginalSearchQueryString, QueryPointer);
                            ContextInstance.InputParameters[QueryLiteral] = QueryPointer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Exception occured in QuickSearch()", ex);
        }
    }


private bool CheckIfTheQueryIsNotForWebResourceAndSearchIsNotByLetter(string entityLogicalName, string originalSearch)
    {

        if (entityLogicalName.ToLower() == "webresource" || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originalSearch) || entityLogicalName.ToLower() == "opportunity")
            return false;

        else if (originalSearch.StartsWith("[") && originalSearch.EndsWith("]%"))
            return false;

        return true;
    }


private string ModifyAllConditionExpressionsInCriteriaToLikeOperator(string OriginalSearchQueryString, QueryExpression QueryPointer)
    {
        if (null != QueryPointer.Criteria)
        {
            //Change the default 'BeginsWith'Operator to 'Contains/Like' operator in the basic search query
            foreach (FilterExpression FilterSet in QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters)
            {
                foreach (ConditionExpression ConditionSet in FilterSet.Conditions)
                {
                    if (ConditionSet.Operator == ConditionOperator.Like)
                    {
                        if (OriginalSearchQueryString != "")
                            ConditionSet.Values[0] = OriginalSearchQueryString;
                        else
                        {
                            OriginalSearchQueryString = QueryPointer.Criteria.Filters[0].Conditions[0].Values[0].ToString();
                            OriginalSearchQueryString = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                             "{0}{1}", LIKE, OriginalSearchQueryString);
                            ConditionSet.Values[0] = OriginalSearchQueryString;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return OriginalSearchQueryString;
    }
```

***Register this plugin as below:***

`Message`**:** `RetrieveMultiple`

`Primary Entity`**:** `none`

`Secondary Entity`**:** `none`

`Eventing Pipleine Stage of Execution`**:** `Pre-Operation`

`Execution Mode`**:**`Synchronous`

Comment: I think this is indeed the only supported way to do it. However, your solution indiscrminately tweaks all `QueryExpression` queries, which will almost certainly lead to undesired side effects. (Think of users using Advanced Find.) So, I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I have implemented this, and advanced find is working fine, i don't know how